# changed to ExitNodes {au}, requiring multiple exit nodes only getting 1

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I changed to ExitNodes {au}, requiring multiple exit nodes only getting 1 single IP address that never changes despite changing identity and circuit and reinstalling. Is this normal to be only assigned 1 resultant IP that wont change if you stipulate a single country?

Also, in turn, does this in fact mean that I DO have a single IP even when im clicking 'change identity' or are there other factors at play that make my 'identity' appear different to the same site?

Kindest

Answer (score 1):

No this isn't abnormal, there are only a small set of Exits in that country (currently [two](https://atlas.torproject.org/#search/country:AU%20flag:Exit)).

While Tor's anonymity doesn't come from having multiple IP addresses, as you mistaken seem to imagine, it does come from being indistinguishable from the crowd.

In your case by picking only AU exits you are forcing your Tor to only ever Exit from locations that other Tor users are very unlikely to exit from. So all of your Tor activity (regardless of New Identity use) can be linked by to a single entity (I.E. you) with reasonable certainty.